# Docker - Cannot create temporary directory

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, docker

**We have a docker hosted in Ubuntu 4.4.0-93-generic.**
When I tried to create a container I got this error:

```
INTERNAL ERROR: Cannot create temporary directory!
```

After some research, I found it was due to the disk space (or lack thereof)

I used `df` to show the disk space. I am not able to understand the below information,

```
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on     
udev                              504G     0  504G   0% /dev           
tmpfs                             101G   42M  101G   1% /run           
/dev/mapper/dev--ubuntu--vg-root   27G   27G     0 100% /              
tmpfs                             504G  428K  504G   1% /dev/shm       
tmpfs                             5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock      
tmpfs                             504G     0  504G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
/dev/sda1                         472M  106M  342M  24% /boot          
/dev/mapper/dev--ubuntu--vg-home   51G  281M   48G   1% /home          
none                               27G   27G     0 100% /var/lib/docker
shm                                64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker
none                               27G   27G     0 100% /var/lib/docker
shm                                64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker
tmpfs                             101G     0  101G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Could anyone please explain what this is and am I running out of space?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the output of `df` instead of taking a screenshot?

Comment: Basically var directory is part of your root file system and this is at 100%. Luckily, you are using logical volumes and so you can provision further disks if required and add the space to the volume.

Comment: On second thought, do `df -h`

Comment: Do you have any link where I could learn more details on this ?

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490784/repartition-hard-drive/490790), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) or [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)

Comment: Updated the question with output text

Comment: Ty @Raajkumar. I did another edit to fix spelling, formatting, & grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, this means that your root filesystem is totally full.

- Clear up some space;
- Change your partition sizes;
- Try [moving to another drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741723/moving-entire-linux-installation-to-another-drive)

Comment: There's a green checkmark beside the up/down arrows; click it to set this answer as accepted. Ty <3

Answer (score 3):

It means that your root storage is full, check by `df -h`.

This method might help you up with removing stale docker images by command below:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

Or using:

```
docker image prune
```